# @ElementCollection org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to store a  `Map<String, Set<String>>` with jpa.

Here is what i have :

```
@ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name="material_index_join", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="paire_Id"))
    @MapKeyColumn (name="material")
    @Column(name="index")
    private Map<String, Set<String>> mapMaterialIndex = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
```

But i get the following error :

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: material_index_join, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(index)]

What can i do ?

Tell me if you need any further information.

Comment: Have a look at [Hibernate doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections-map), I don't think you can map a `Map` of `Set`, both key and value of the map should have cardinality 1, for instance `Map<String, String>`.
if you need to map a `ManyToMany` look at these [How to map an association as a java.util.Map](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/map-association-java-util-map/)

Comment: You aren't considering HOW you would want that stored, in what table(s), and what columns. And in JPA you cannot store Sets of Sets, or Maps or Sets directly. If the value of the map was mapped using an `AttributeConverter` **then** it could be possible if your JPA provider allows it (because the value could then be stored in a single column in the other table)

Comment: Can you describe the tables and columns you have?